# Livewire pass the changed input value to the component function

Tags: laravel-livewire

So I have a livewire component with multiple inputs in it. I'm trying to pass the value into the component so it can be saved and all fields updated after totals etc being done.
Here is one of my inputs:

```
<input
    wire:change="update({{ $row->id }}, 'rate', {{ $row->rate }}"
    name="quote_{{ $row->id }}_rate"
    class="w-full"
    type="text"
    value="{{ $row->rate }}"
/>
```

This calls the update function in my livewire component

```
    public function update( $id, $type, $value ) {
        $item = QuoteItem::find( $id );
        $item->{$type} = $value;
        $item->total = $item->hours * $item->rate;
        $item->save();

        $this->quoteItems = QuoteItem::where( 'quote_id', $this->number )->get();
        $this->refreshTotals();
    }
```

However the `$value` is always the original; unchanged value and it then resets the element to what it was originally.

These inputs are in a table so there will be multiple rows with rate otherwise I'd just bind to a model right? So how do I pass the changed input into this function?

*** EDIT ***
I initially had a livewire component would this be a better route with this than putting everything in a single place?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

When I look at your code, the value of `rate` never changes. You're basically always passing the same value to this `update` function. If you want to get the changed value, I suggest using the magic [$event](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/actions#magic-actions) variable:

`wire:change="update({{$row->id}}, 'rate', $event.target.value)"`

Just some other troubleshooting/tips:

- I suggest using [wire:key](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-issues) on every row (if it's a `foreach` loop), so Livewire "knows" better when changes happen.
- You're missing a closing bracket (`)`) after your `update` call in your `wire:change`.
- I assume `row->rate` is always a numeric value? Else it should be between quotes.